# Using JWT instead of Cookie on SSL enabled site

Tags: security, cookies, jwt

Instead of using a cookie I'm using a JWT token which gets send with every request. Every request is a POST request so that the token does not get saved in the browser's history.

It's a single-page app.

The token looks like:

```
{
    userId: 12345678,
    expires: <UNIX timestamp>,
    otherInfo: <something>
}
```

Everything is SSL secured.
The token is created on the server when the user logs on.

Would this be a good way to replace a cookie or do you see any flaws?

Comment: Why would browser history be a problem for a single-page-app even for GET requests? AJAX requests do not land in browser history. But better put the token into "Authorization" header anyway so it does not accidentally appear in access logs if you use GET after all.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good solution. Using cookies (with a `httpOnly` flag) for cross-request persistence is *not* optional - it's the only way to safely store session credentials, in such a way that on-page JavaScript code cannot access it directly.

This is essential to prevent eg. session stealing in an XSS attack, by ensuring that scripts cannot access the credentials, but they can still be used in requests to the server.

Your use of JWT doesn't seem to really solve a problem, either - why can't you just use session cookies using an existing session implementation? This kind of thing is precisely is what they're made for.